# Using Async causing: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module asyncToGenerator.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a problem with "async" in babel and node js that i couldn't solve for days... the error bellow:

`Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\BOOSTACKSTICK\BOOSTACK\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\esm\asyncToGenerator.js [1] require() of ES modules is not supported. [1] require() of C:\BOOSTACKSTICK\BOOSTACK\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\esm\asyncToGenerator.js from C:\BOOSTACKSTICK\BOOSTACK\prod-server\api\auth\auth-controller.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules. [1] Instead rename asyncToGenerator.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\BOOSTACKSTICK\BOOSTACK\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\esm\package.json.`

I compile my dev-server folder to a prod-server with config bellow
**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "babel dev-server --out-dir prod-server && vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "dev": "concurrently \"babel dev-server --out-dir prod-server --watch\" \"nodemon prod-server/index.js\" \"npm run serve\" "
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/node": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.8",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "compass-mixins": "^0.12.10",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
  },
```

**.babelrc**

```
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage", // or "entry"
        "corejs": 3,
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "corejs": 3
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
  ]
}
```

**Environment**

```
Node: v12.16.3
Babel: 7.12.3
```

**Simple code with "async" that causing a problem **

```
export async function index(req, res) {
  return res.status(200).json({ user: "user" });
}
```

** Babel Output**

```
"use strict";

var _interopRequireDefault = require("C:/BOOSTACKSTICK/BOOSTACK/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");

var _Object$defineProperty = require("@babel/runtime-corejs3/core-js-stable/object/define-property");

_Object$defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

exports.index = index;

var _regenerator = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime-corejs3/regenerator"));

require("regenerator-runtime/runtime");

var _asyncToGenerator2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("C:/BOOSTACKSTICK/BOOSTACK/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator"));

//Check And Validate Request (LOGIN METHODE)
function index(_x, _x2) {
  return _index.apply(this, arguments);
}

function _index() {
  _index = (0, _asyncToGenerator2.default)( /*#__PURE__*/_regenerator.default.mark(function _callee(req, res) {
    return _regenerator.default.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
      while (1) {
        switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
          case 0:
            return _context.abrupt("return", res.status(200).json({
              user: "user"
            }));

          case 1:
          case "end":
            return _context.stop();
        }
      }
    }, _callee);
  }));
  return _index.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

**Possible Solution**
the only workaround i tested to avoid this error is to modify manually the `node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\esm\package.json` to remove `"type": module` and remove `import`  from `node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\esm\asyncToGenerator.js`

is it a bug or i'm doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: I have the same issue bug with @babel/runtime/helpers/esm/arrayWithoutHoles.js

Comment: @MirzaAndriamanamisoa this is the reponse i got from the babel team : https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/12299   in my side, after a long thinking i realized that i don't really need it(babel)... so i remove it